# Deleting RAR files from temp folder?

Tags: c#, .net

I am currently working on tool that will delete stuff in my temp folder and I've made it so it deletes Files such as text files and folders but how do I make it so it deletes RAR files and JPG's etc? is it possible?

This is my current code

```
private void Clear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string tempPath = Path.GetTempPath();
    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(tempPath);

    foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in di.GetDirectories())
    {
        try
        {
           dir.Delete(true);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // Log error.
            continue;
        }  
    }

    foreach (FileInfo file in di.GetFiles())
    {
        try
        {
            file.Delete();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // Log error.
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The code example above is simply deleting everything, which would include RAR files as well...

Comment: Are you getting any errors? I don't see why this code would only single out .txt files and folders.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `DirectoryInfo.GetFiles()` can accept a search pattern parameter.

```
foreach (FileInfo file in di.GetFiles("*.jpg"))
{
    file.Delete();
}
```

This would delete any file with `.jpg` extension. You can do the same for `.rar`

Optionally I would suggest creating a method to do this.

```
public void DeleteFiles(DirectoryInfo di, string searchPattern)
{
    foreach (FileInfo file in di.GetFiles(searchPattern))
    {
        file.Delete();
    }
}
```

Once this is created then you can just it like this.

```
DeleteFiles(di, "*.jpg");
```

If you have a list of all the extensions that you need you can loop through them.

```
string[] extentionList = new[] {"*.jpg", "*.rar", "*.bmp", "*.gif"};

foreach (string extension in extentionList)
{
    DeleteFiles(di, extension);
}
```

If you will be using this in a variety of places, converting it to a `DirectoryInfo` extension method would be the best choice.

Comment: In the method you created how would i impliment the extensions? Such as .rar & .jpg

Comment: Oh I create strings with the extensions?

Comment: @Alexander.Matt Yes, just use a string as is shown in this example.

Comment: @MattRowland One last question, when creating the string, do I need to include the "." in the extension? or just like this
string jpg, png, rar;

Comment: You need the `*` as well as the `.`. This signifies the search pattern. If you are creating the method. You could always make the method concatenate the `*.`

Comment: Ooh! Okay I get it now! Thank you so much!